# devise a perceptron to jugde parity such as 1 2 3 4 

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Devise a perceptron, achieve a function that judges parity of 1 2 3 4 ....using matlab I have train a neural network, but it has very large variance.

I want to ask how to express sample?

If I directly use 1 2 3 4 5...as sample, the variance is very large. In the other words, the neural network is not used to classfiy.

I want to ask if the other functions can be used to transform the sample?

This is the program:

```
P= [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14]; % Question if I can use another form to express the sample
T= [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]; 
net=newp([-1 10],1);  
net.trainParam.epochs = 40;
net=train(net,P,T); 
Y=sim(net,P)             
E1=mae(Y-T)        
plotpv(P,Y);       
plotpc(net.iw{1},net.b{1})
```

Comment: yes  can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: why?  no people can answer my qustion .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question... but, I thought it worth mentioning that the (single layer) [perceptron is (famously) unable to compute exclusive-or (XOR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#History).  The binary logic XOR function is equivalent to calculating parity for two bits.  For this reason, while I'm not familiar with that specific Matlab package, I expect you to need a multi-layer perceptron... perhaps one with more layers than bits in the input string.  If you were to use a perceptron model with too few layers - I'd expect you to fail to train it to calculate parity bits.

Calculating parity is not a task to which the perceptron is ideally suited. :)